# Apache2 ignored virtualHost for Subdomain, uses default virtualHost instead

Tags: debian, virtualhost, apache2

I'm running Apache2 (2.4.10) on Debian 9.1. I've several Subdomains configured in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/" and activated with a2ensite ***.

All Subdomains are working as expected except for one. This one is ignored and the default virtualHost is used.

Let's say my Domain is myDomain.com.
I have serveral config files:
- aaa.myDomain.com
- bbb.myDomain.com
- ccc.myDomain.com
- myDomain.com
- xxx.myDomain.com
- zzz.myDomain.com

The zzz.myDomain.com one is the one not working. I've copied a existing and working config File, switched the names in it and it's still not working.
All Subdomain configs have the same, just the given names changed.

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@myDomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zzz.myDomain.com
  ServerName zzz.myDomain.com
  ServerAlias *.zzz.myDomain.com
  ErrorLog logs/zzz.myDomain.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/zzz.myDomain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The default virtual Host is configured like this

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@myDomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName myDomain.com
  ErrorLog logs/myDomain.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/myDomain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2ctl -S gives the following output

```
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
default server myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myDomain.com.conf:2)
port 80 namevhost myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myDomain.com.conf:2)
port 80 namevhost aaa.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/aaa.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.aaa.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost demo.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/demo.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.demo.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost bbb.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bbb.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.bbb.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost ccc.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ccc.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.ccc.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost ddd.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ddd.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.ddd.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost eee.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/eee.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.eee.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost fff.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/fff.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.fff.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost ggg.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ggg.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.ggg.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myDomain.com.conf:2)
       alias myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost xxx.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxx.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.xxx.myDomain.com
port 80 namevhost zzz.myDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zzz.myDomain.com.conf:2)
       wild alias *.zzz.myDomain.com
```